# Helping find Database Candidate Keys, Primary Keys

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to work on this model and figure out the following questions about it:

1. What is (are) the candidate key(s) of PATIENT_VISIT?
2. If there is more than one candidate key, select a primary key from among the candidate keys.
3. Based on the primary key chosen, what normal form violations exist in PATIENT_VISIT?
4. Develop a solution that eliminates the normal form violations.
   Is your solution a lossless-join decomposition?
5. Is your solution dependency-preserving? If not, how can dependency preservation be 
   achieved? Is this revised solution in BCNF?
6. Provide a solution that meets all three of the following conditions: (1) is in BCNF, (2) is dependency-preserving, and (3) is a lossless-join decomposition

   ```
   +---------+------------+------------+
   | Patient |  Hospital  |   Doctor   |
   +---------+------------+------------+
   | Smith   | Methodist  | D. Cooley  |
   | Lee     | St. Luke's | Z. Zhang   |
   | Marks   | Methodist  | D. Cooley  |
   | Marks   | St. Luke's | W. Lowe    |
   | Lou     | Hermann R. | Duke       |
   +---------+------------+------------+
   ```

In addition, suppose the following semantic rules exist.

- Each patient may be a patient in several hospitals.
- For each hospital, a patient may have only one doctor.
- Each hospital has several doctors.
- Each doctor uses only one hospital.
- Each doctor treats several patients in one hospital.

Comment: Candidate keys = any single column or group of columns that uniquely and reliably identifies a single row amongst a whole table; primary key = one of those candidate keys, chosen at your liking

Answer (score 1):

1. {Patient, Doctor} is a candidate key.  The only other possible key is {Patient, Hospital, Doctor}, but that is not minimal because of the FD Doctor ⟶ Hospital; it is a superkey but not a candidate key.
2. Moot; there's only one candidate key.
3. The schema is not in BCNF because of the transitive dependency (FD) Doctor ⟶ Hospital. (Each attribute of the table is functionally determined by the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.)
4. PD { Patient, Doctor }, DH { Doctor, Hospital }.  This is a lossless decomposition.
5. This solution is dependency preserving.
6. See 4.